# Unexpected token import Using React Jasmine Babel Webpack

Tags: reactjs, testing, webpack, jasmine

Trying to write some Jasmine tests for my React App, and getting this error:

```
import HomePage from '../../src/components/home/HomePage';

^^^^^^SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.jasmine.executeSpecsInFolder (C:\Users\JasmineTest\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\index.js:160:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JasmineTest\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js:248:9)
```

Using React, Babel-loader, webpack.
Only gives error if i try to import component, or if i use required('component') and in component i use Import.

Comment: can we see your babelrc? doesn't look like babel is running when you're running tests.

Comment: {
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}